# Server not receiving from client. Linux TCP/IP communication

Tags: c++, linux, tcp, server

I am running a server application in linux OS to recv messages from client and then based on the message the server should send response back to the client. Its not a one time process, I am running the server continuosly to listen for messages and then it should send the response back.

The issue I am facing is that, for every one send message from server, its not receiving the consecuting message from client and then at the second attempt its receiving.But then at the client end the message is shown as being sent. If I disable the send part the sever is receiving the messages without any issue.

Is there any thing I am doing wrong here?

```
#include "server.h"

server::server(int port)
{
    bufferLength = 1024;
    buffer = new char[bufferLength+1];
    portNo = port;
    client = -1;
}

server::~server()
{
    delete buffer;
}

void server::run() {
    createSocket();
    serve();
}

void server::createSocket(){
    sockId = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    cout << "socketId "<<sockId<<" port is "<<this->portNo<<endl;
    if (!sockId) {
        perror("socket");
        exit(-1);
    }

    struct sockaddr_in serverAddress;
    memset(&serverAddress,0,sizeof(serverAddress));
    serverAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddress.sin_port = htons(portNo);
    serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    int reUse = 1;
    if (setsockopt(sockId, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &reUse, sizeof(reUse)) < 0) {
        perror("setsockopt");
        exit(-1);
    }

    if (bind(sockId,(const struct sockaddr *)&serverAddress,sizeof(serverAddress)) < 0) {
        perror("bind");
        exit(-1);
    }

    if (listen(sockId,SOMAXCONN) < 0) {
        perror("listen");
        exit(-1);
    }

}

void server::closeSocket(){
    int status;
    status = close(sockId);
    if (!status) {
        perror("socket");
        exit(-1);
    }
}

void server::serve() {
    struct sockaddr_in clientAddress;
    socklen_t clientLength = sizeof(clientAddress);

    while ((client = accept(sockId,(struct sockaddr *)&clientAddress,&clientLength)) > 0) {
        getMessage(client);
    }
    closeSocket();
}

void server::handle(int client) {
    getMessage(client);
    close(client);
}

void server::getMessage(int client) {
    int result;
    cout<<"receive client "<<client<<endl;
    result = recv(client,buffer,1024,0);

    if(result <= 0)
        perror("receive function failed or finished");

    cout <<"ROI "<<buffer<<endl;

    char* output = NULL;
    output = strstr(buffer,"end");
    char* output3 = NULL;
    output3 = strstr(buffer,"get");

    if(output){
        strncpy(output,"",3);
        writeNewRoi();
        cout<<"restarting "<<endl;
        system("sudo ./restart_detection.sh");
    }

    if(output3){
        sendRoi(client);
    }
}

void server::writeNewRoi(){
    ofstream outfile("ROI.txt");
    outfile << buffer;
    outfile.close();
}

void server::sendRoi(int client){
    ifstream roiFile;
    roiFile.open("ROI.txt");
    string str;
    while(!roiFile.eof()){
        getline(roiFile,str);
        str +=  "\n";
        const char* message = str.c_str();

        int nleft = str.length();
        int nwritten;

        while (nleft) {
            nwritten = send(client, message, nleft, 0);
            nleft -= nwritten;
            message += nwritten;
        }
    }
    roiFile.close();

    char endMsg[] = "end";
    send(client, endMsg, strlen(endMsg), 0);
}
```

Comment: TCP doesn't send messages, it sends a byte stream. You mustn't expect a one-to-one correspondence between `send()` and `recv()`. You need to implement some way of detecting message boundaries in the application protocol.

Comment: Two notes: Concerning your question, you should have extracted and provided a [mcve]. Strictly, your question is off-topic because you didn't. Please also take the [tour] and read [ask]. Concerning your problem, using e.g. ZeroMQ instead of the low-level Berkeley Sockets API would probably be beneficial.